# SQL Server multiple update query statements

Tags: sql-server

This is my SQL Server table:

[image]

I want to update the table so that `bill_no` is starting from 1 by replacing 193 and should replace accordingly as shown in the table.

I have tried this by executing a single SQL update query, but it is time-consuming and a lengthy process for thousands of rows of data.

What I have tried:

```
update tbl_sales_record 
set bill_no = 1 
where bill_no = 193
```

How to change `bill_no` column at once from 1 respectively?

Comment: What would be the expected result you want?

Comment: Your question is vague, so I'm guessing. Is this what you want to do?: https://dbfiddle.uk/HG2MjJZD

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
UPDATE tbl_sales_record SET bill_no = bill_no - 192;
```

Though I can see that `bill_no` starts from `192`, so it will become `0` in that case.

In short, this query will decrese the every `bill_no` cell data by an amount of `192`.